# Неправильная работа jQuery UI range slider

Tags: jquery-ui, jquery

Здравствуйте!
Столкнулся с проблемой. Использую следующий код:

```
$(function() {
    var min_cost = $("input[name='min-cost']").val(); 
    console.log(min_cost); //3828

    var max_cost = $("input[name='max-cost']").val();
    console.log(max_cost); //25289

    $( "#slider-range" ).slider({
        range: true,
        min: min_cost,
        max: max_cost,
        values: [ min_cost, max_cost ],
        slide: function( event, ui ) {
            $( "#mincost" ).val(ui.values[ 0 ]);
            $( "#maxcost" ).val(ui.values[ 1 ]);
        }
    });
        $( "#mincost" ).val( $( "#slider-range" ).slider( "values", 0 ) );
            $( "#maxcost" ).val( $( "#slider-range" ).slider( "values", 1 ) );
});
```

Оба ползунка встают на минимальном значении и не хотят двигаться. В чём может быть проблема? Если не использовать переменные для задания диапазона и минимального и максимального значения, то всё работает.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Пример закиньте. Как вариант предложить - это переводить значения в числовой тип: parseInt/parseFloat

Comment: Спасибо! parseInt помог :)